# Secure https url from tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to get **https** url from tomcat server by following.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
          maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
          keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="key-password"
          clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

But it gives insecure **https** url.

Can i get secure **https** url from tomcat server where i can distribute my apps?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The connector just makes tomcat listen on port 8443, it doesn't generate any URL.  Please specify more clearly what you're doing that doesn't "give" you the URL you need. Also what you consider the difference between a "insecure https URL" and a "secure https URL" (or is that a typo and you meant http in the first case?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing the red `"Not Secure"` **<strike>https</strike>**  is because the certificate that you have provided is self-signed. If you get a signed certificate from any authorized vendor and use that certificate, you'll get the green `"Secure"` like you want.